# Authenticate with OneDrive SDK in Xamarin Android App

Tags: android, xamarin, onedrive

I use the onedrive SDK in a Cross Plattform app. On Windows the Authentication works via the OneDriveClientExtensions.GetClientUsingWebAuthenticationBroker.

Now I'm trying to login on Android. I tried it with this:

```
oneDriveClient = OneDriveClient.GetMicrosoftAccountClient(
                    appId: MSA_CLIENT_ID,
                    returnUrl: RETURN_URL,
                    scopes: scopes,
                    clientSecret: MSA_CLIENT_SECRET);
                await oneDriveClient.AuthenticateAsync();
```

But get an error that no valid token could be received. Do I have to implement a own AuthenticationProvider inhereting from WebAuthenticationBrokerAuthenticationProvider who shows a browser for the oauth? Or what would be the way to go here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this using the Xamarin Auth Component. Heres the code who calls the webview with the login:

```
        private const string RETURN_URL = @"https://login.live.com/oauth20_desktop.srf";

private void ShowWebView()
    {
        var auth = new OAuth2Authenticator(
                clientId: MSA_CLIENT_ID,
                scope: string.Join(",", scopes),
                authorizeUrl: new Uri(GetAuthorizeUrl()),
                redirectUrl: new Uri(RETURN_URL));

        auth.Completed += (sender, eventArgs) =>
        {
            if (eventArgs.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                //Do Something
            }
        };

        var intent = auth.GetUI(Application.Context);
        intent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);

        Application.Context.StartActivity(intent);
    }

    private string GetAuthorizeUrl()
    {
        var requestUriStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        requestUriStringBuilder.Append("https://login.live.com/oauth20_authorize.srf");
        requestUriStringBuilder.AppendFormat("?{0}={1}", Constants.Authentication.RedirectUriKeyName, RETURN_URL);
        requestUriStringBuilder.AppendFormat("&{0}={1}", Constants.Authentication.ClientIdKeyName, MSA_CLIENT_ID);
        requestUriStringBuilder.AppendFormat("&{0}={1}", Constants.Authentication.ScopeKeyName,
            string.Join("%20", scopes));
        requestUriStringBuilder.AppendFormat("&{0}={1}", Constants.Authentication.ResponseTypeKeyName,
            Constants.Authentication.TokenResponseTypeValueName);

        return requestUriStringBuilder.ToString();
    }
```